# drop markers on new thread

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a list of about 2000 elements of my CustomClass which has `LatLng` as one of the attributes. So basically I want to drop all 2000 markers on the map but dropping all of them makes the map laggy. So I decided to implement lazy loading for the map. I have a HashMap that holds markers that are dropped in the visible region. Below is how I implemented it.

I iterate over my list and check to see if the item's `LatLng` coordinates are inside the visible. I do that using `LatLngBounds.contains()` method. If the item's coordinates are in the visible region, then I drop the marker and add it to the HashMap. If item's coordinates are not in the visible region, it should not be on map and I remove it from map if it's there.

Below code is in `onCameraIdleListener()` and gets executed everytime the map is moved or zoommed in/out

```
for (Event event: listOfEvents) {
    LatLng latLng = event.getCoordinates();
    LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
    boolean isMarkerOnMap = markerksOnMap.contains(latLng);
    if bounds.contains(latLng) {
        if (!isMarkerOnMap) {
            // add marker
            markersOnMap.add(latLng);
        }
    }
    else if (isMarkerOnMap) {
        // remove marker
        markersOnMap.remove(latLng);
    }
}
```

This code above works but my map is still laggy. What happens is when the map is moved, the for loop iterates over the 2000 elements and it takes a few seconds for the loop to process. While that is happening, the map freezes and I can't move the map or zoom in/out.

Should I put the for-loop in an Async thread? Any example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can use the async mechanism (asynctask / thread / rxjava) just for populate all of the marker

so when add generated marker the **markersOnMap** (it happen the main thread) just delete all the marker and replace it from the result of the async process

example on asynctask ():

```
class GenerateMarkerTask extends AsyncTask(List<Event>, Integer, List<Marker>) {

protected List<Marker> doInBackground(List<Event>... events) {
    List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList();
    for (Event event: listOfEvents) {
        LatLng latLng = event.getCoordinates();
        LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
        boolean isMarkerOnMap = markerksOnMap.contains(latLng);
            if bounds.contains(latLng) {
                if (!isMarkerOnMap) {
                    // add marker
                    markers.add(latLng);
                }
            }
    }

}

protected void onPostExecute(List<Marker> result) {
    markerksOnMap.clear();
    for (Marker marker: result) {
        markersOnMap.add(result);
    }

 }

}
```

then on onCameraIdleListener() just run

```
new GenerateMarkerTask.execute(listOfEvents);
```